# Run python script with disk as RAM

Tags: python, memory, out-of-memory, disk

I have low memory VPS container based (LXC), therefore I can't change kernel parameter such as swap memory swappiness. Even though there is swap allocated from built-in VPS when I check with `htop`, I don't know why OOM killer still killing `myprogram.py` and seems didn't utilize the swap when memory is 100% used.

Therefore I want to run `myprogram.py` with utilizing disk as main memory without modifying main script, I have my code like this:

```
def main():
  import numpy as np
  terrible_memory_alloc = np.zeros(99999999)

if __name__=='__main__':
  main()
```

I expect there is wrapper like this that will allocate memory to disk when memory is being full:

```
def main():
  import numpy as np
  terrible_memory_alloc = np.zeros(99999999)

if __name__=='__main__':
  with open('myvirtualram.file', 'wb') as file:
    run_inside_disk(main, file)
```

Comment: No, there's no such facility because the OS usually handles it.